# Format timezone into 2 digits in moment js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using moment js for displaying time

Currently I am able to display the proper syntax I am looking for but I have a question and please see example below:

here is my current output
**THU 23 NOVEMBER, 13:07:21 (UTC+08:00)**

Is it possible to make the timezone look like 
**THU 23 NOVEMBER, 13:07:21 (UTC+08)**

Here is my code

```
var time = moment().format('ddd D MMMM, HH:mm:ss [(UTC]Z[)]').toUpperCase();
```

Please see this fiddle I created (http://jsfiddle.net/m90qy0s5/)
Appreciate your help.

Comment: You want to ignore the min section ? Isn't a important factor in defining the UTC Offset ?

Comment: `'ddd D MMMM, HH:mm:ss (UTCZZ)'` http://jsfiddle.net/m90qy0s5/1/